# iOS enterprise program - In-house Distribution

Tags: ios, deployment

I'm development a app for iPad that will be used within the company only.
As the devices that will use the app will be more than 100, the company need to join iOS enterprise program.

How works the distribution for In-house distribution?

I need to register all the devices to generate one Certificate for the app? Or I can generate one Certificate and the app will work on every devices?

Apple need to approve the application for In-house distribution?

The company's objective for distribution will be deploy the application on their website so the employees can access the web site, login, and download the app for theirs devices. There is any roles from apple that does not approve this method? What is the best method for distribution In-house app?

Comment: @FreedomI am facing the same problem, can you please tell me the correct way that how can i publish my app in multiple employees using IOS Enterprise program? Thanks

Comment: @APG I ended up not using the enterprise program. The company changed the target of the application. Now, I have to register the devices(they are not many) that will use the application, and publish on a web application. The users will access the web application from there's devices and download the application. From what I can tell, with iOS enterprise program you just need to build and publish(No need to register devices).Any user will be free to download the application from web application or mail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

> 1)You don't need to register devices on provisioning portal for
>   "in-house" distribution. Apps built with these profiles can be
>   installed on any iOS device.
>
> 2)Enterprise apps don't undergo Apples's review process as they are
>   not meant to be distributed through the app-store. In fact Apple
>   doesn't have any role in enterprise app distribution cycle.
>
> 3)You can distribute app through any medium you want, within your
>   enterprise, OTA, Intranet or mail(I have seen distribution through all
>   these mediums in my enterprise).

However the license agreement says that you can't distribute enterprise apps to anyone outside your enterprise, not even your clients. You can demo the app to people who don't belong to you enterprise, but they should only be installed on devices owned by the enterprise or employees of the enterprise.

Comment: Is there a copy of the full text of the agreement online somewhere?

Comment: @JeremyWhite I don't think so. It would be available to people whose enterprises have this license or you may try contacting Apple directly for the full text of the agreement.

Comment: So when you say "Apps built with these profiles can be installed on any iOS device." do you mean I can take a brand new out of the box iOS device and install one of my enterprise apps on it?  I don't need to install the distribution provisioning profile?

Comment: @DanF sorry for the late reply. You may have found out this by now...the answer is yes. You would only need an in-house distribution profile.

Comment: @Vin my question was more of does the profile need to be manually installed on the destination device, or does being signed with the enterprise distribution profile allow the device to install the app

Comment: An app built with an in-house distribution profile can be installed on any iOS device.

Comment: So one can distribute in-house enterprise apps to personal employee devices? Re: "devices owned by the enterprise or employees of the enterprise."