# How to rebrand (and redistribute) iOS iPad application?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have application in App Store. A client approached me asking if he can get the same application but with different name, different graphics and little other changes installed on his iPads - 150 of them. If that would be 10 iPads - i would do a custom build, add all iPads into provisioning certificate, and  that would be it. But that won't work for 150 iPads. So what are my options? So far I can think about the following:

1. Open 2 more dev accounts and add UUIDs into them - but I have a feeling that Apple won't like this.
2. Do the required changes - and submit the app into App Store with different name
3. Figure something out with Enterprise distribution - but I do not think it will work from legal point of view - my client wants to install the apps on his clients' iPads - so it's clearly NOT "in-house" distribution.

So far **option #2 looks the most promising to me** - submit as a different app to App Store. But I'm afraid that Apple will not let almost identical app to go into App Store. Especially if I submit it from the same account as the primary app. Can Apple block me for this? Any other ideas?

---

**UPDATE & SOLUTION**

I will combine here my learnings with @vikingosegundo's answer.

**UPDATE TO OPTION 2 - submit to app store with different name**:

some links say it's possible: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/123906/white-label-apps---is-approval-possible-apple- - and okay to do this. I did not find explicit restriction to this in  [app store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> 2.20 Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

I do not believe two or three would count as many, and would count as SPAM if you clearly rebrand it. But of course it's up to Apple.

**UPDATE TO OPTION #3 - going with Enterprise distribution:**

that's what I decided to do at the end. I called apple support @1-800-633-2152 - and real person answered :) My biggest concern was that iPads I wanted to distribute the app do not belong to my client's business - so technically speaking it's not "in-house distribution". However they said that

> enterprise is OK because the app would be used by the enterprise
>   holder (my client), and it doesn't matter who owns the iPad

**NEW OPTION #4 - Volume Purchase Program**

Apple's [Volume Purchase Program](https://www.apple.com/business/vpp/) looks like exactly what we need actually:

> The Volume Purchase Program also provides a way to get custom B2B apps
>   built by third-party developers to meet the unique needs of your
>   business.

at this moment YOU have to be US business to enroll into this program - but they are looking to expand it to more countries soon.

Comment: how big is the app and does it need to run offline? My personal pref is to do such things as a bootstrap web app.

Comment: it is existing already, as described, it would be a re-branded app.

Comment: You might find some of these resources helpful regarding the iOS Enterprise Program and it intentions/limitations: In-House App Development Guide (http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/In-house_App_Accelerator_Guide.pdf); iOS Enterprise Program FAQ (https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html)

Comment: @Isotope - can you please explain what does "bootstrap web app" mean?

Comment: Twitter bootstrap is a CSS / js library which scales applications to the device they're running on. So if you built a web application (website) using bootstrap then you can do what you want with it. I believe this website uses bootstrap just looking at it while I write this on my iPhone, but I could be wrong.

Comment: you got lots more information out of apple than I did. I onced ask if owning means that the ipad must be purchased by that very person or if it is ok, if the person just allows me to install something on it. and I also asked, what is covered by the word in-house. answer: ask your own lawyer, apple is not provided legal advices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess, if a single customer owns 150 iPads, he can be seen as a organization — and the iPods would be something like "in-House" (what ever this term means). You wrote nothing about your customer, but he should check, if he can get a [DUNS number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Universal_Numbering_System), and get himself a enterprise account that you could administer to distribute the app.

If a DUNS number is available, I'd go with **3.**

**2.**: I don't think, that apple would like rebranded apps
I had a look into the [app store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). **2.20** and **2.22** might apply.

**1.**: remember, that the certificates on each device needs to be updated regular. might be quite a hassle for you or the user.

PS: I didn't read them yet, but Apple has this free books:

- [iOS Deployment Scenarios](http://itunes.apple.com/us/book/ios-deployment-scenarios/id499335673?mt=11), <sub>[PDF](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Business_Mar12.pdf)</sub>
- [In-house App Development Accelerator Guide](http://itunes.apple.com/us/book/in-house-app-accelerator-guide/id499341792?mt=11), <sub>[PDF](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/In-house_App_Accelerator_Guide.pdf)</sub>

PS2: Maybe [*Volume purchase Program for Business*](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) is a way to go, but only available in the US right now :(

> **Coming Soon.** The App Store Volume Purchase Program is expanding to the following countries: Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Italy, Japan, New Zealand, Spain, and United Kingdom.

Comment: this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293917/ios-enterprise-program-in-house-distribution says that I can't distribute apps to clients. As I said in my original post, my client has a bunch of "subclients" - so same thing applies to him unfortunately.

Comment: one year ago I registered an enterprise account for a company that I am not working for anymore. A lady from apple called me, as she was confused, as we also registered for a normal account the very same moment. she ask me, if I understand, that I dont need both, and why we need a enterprise account. I answered, that we want to distribute the same app — just changed for some special needs — to special customer. this was totally fine for her and we got approved.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing #2 also...and when you write in Review Notes when you submit it that it's basically the same app only with some custom modifications ...after all you own the source code of the original app so you can release as many copies as you like.

You could write in the description too..that it's a modified version of the original app. I don't see any problems there.

A plus to this solution is that you might sell some of these apps too (i mean the modified version) and if you don't want it to remain on the app store just remove app from sale after your client bought the apps he wanted.